# ASP.NET Publishing with old assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, publish

I have a strange problem when publishing my application. The Publish fails with the following error message :-

> ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly
>   'libttsapi_dotnet20' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format.

My solution builds fine, but it will not publish.

I have the configuration manager settings set to "Any CPU" and i've tried changing it to x64 or x86, but the same fault persists.

Has anyone came across this problem or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

neoapi requires x86. Go to Build -> Publish YourProject.  In there choose Settings then File Publish Options and check 'Delete all existing files prior to publish'.  Also check 'Precompile during publishing'.